# What is the process when travelling from state to state in the USA on a B2 visa?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas

Due to a previous conviction, someone in my party could not get an ESTA, so they have a B2 visa. I know that when entering the USA, if you have a conviction, immigration will usually pull you in and question you, but my question is - will they do this when flying from state to state or is it just when entering the USA?

Answer (score 17):

There are no border checkpoints at all between states within the US. After your B2 holder enters the US, they should have no further problems while they remain inside the US borders.

In some places near land borders (with Mexico and Canada), there are CBP checkpoints where they will double check your documentation, if you are travelling by road. If your B2 holder has been admitted, these should not pose any further problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply. Sorry maybe should’ve been more specific we are flying from state to state so not sure if this changes anything or if you have any more information on that, thanks.

Comment: There are still no border checkpoints when flying. Very rarely you might encounter CBP agents upon arriving at your destination, but they would most likely be looking for somebody very specific who they know is on that plane.

Comment: @Emma1234 it doesn't change anything.  There are no immigration checks for domestic flights.  TSA checks ID -- which for most people on a B-2 visa can only be a passport -- to ensure that the traveler is the person named on the boarding pass.  That's it.  (If the traveler's conviction is related to terrorism, they might be on the no-fly list, but if that's the case then they'll never get to the US as they will be unable to board the plane.

Comment: "Very rarely you might encounter CBP agents upon arriving at your destination": this happened once as far as I'm aware, and it was so irregular that it made national news.

Comment: I've been through a couple of CBP road checkpoints recently and if you look even halfway normal they don't bother to stop you.  But of course if you are within [100 miles of any border](https://www.aclu.org/know-your-rights/border-zone) technically the CBP can check you.

Comment: @PeterM CBP or Border Patrol?

Comment: @phoog Customs and Border Patrol

Comment: @PeterM CBP is Customs and Border _Protection._  They have blue uniforms and operate ports of entry on the actual border.  If you were at an interior immigration checkpoint it would have been operated by the green-uniformed officers of the US Border Patrol.

Comment: @phoog So many typos.  But yes, the interior checkpoints, so "protection".  I never paid attention to the color of their uniforms.  And I was never stopped anyway.

Comment: @phoog The US Border Patrol is part of the CBP. Green or blue, it's the same agency.

Comment: @littleadv Border Patrol is part of Customs and Border Protection, but it is distinct from the Office of Field Operations.  Because of OFO's nondescript name, its officers are generally referred to as "CBP officers."  Border Patrol has a different mission, its agents receive different training, its checkpoints are inside the country rather than at ports of entry, and the procedures as well as legal rights and responsibilities of officers and travelers alike are very different.

Comment: @PeterM the interior checkpoints are operated by Border Patrol, so "patrol," not "protection."

Comment: @phoog not sure what is the argument you're trying to make or why it matters, really